# What tools do I need to make a GIS/GPS Navigation Software by C#

Tags: c#, embedded, gps, gis

I have been assigned to know to how to make a **GPS Navigation Software** for Win CE 6.0 operating system. But after searching a lot, I couldn't find a good way to start.

I have downloaded some free software by which i can view the provided ShapeFile files but **I want to make a software**  by which I can view those files in my customized mode.

My preferred technology is .NET 3.5 / 4 and my OS supports silverlight.

You can visit **[this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvKSizyn_vc)** link what exactly I want to do.

Thanks in advance.

I have to work on a predefined data set (shape files) provided by my client and i have to put my app in  GlobalSat [GA-5718] device.

Your suggestions are very fine but it won't work for me. Thats why I am in a confusing position.

Comment: I have Googled a lot but since I am very new in this area, I am confused about the starting point. Thanks for your suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first you'll need to get access to the GPS data and read it. Most GPS modules act as a serial device on some COM port and provide their information in the NMEA Standard.

To get this easily read you should take a look at the [OpenNETCF Serial Library](http://serial.codeplex.com/), cause it provides an easy access to the informations and is able to read the NMEA strings.

But most GPS modems needed to be initialized by sending a correct NMEA input string. For these you should take a look into [this documentation](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/GPS/NMEA%20Reference%20Manual1.pdf), [this site](http://www.deanandara.com/Argonaut/Sensors/Gps/ConfiguringSirfStarIII.html) or [in the comment in the source above function `public bool SendGpsMessage(string GPSSentence)`](http://serial.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/25883#435376).

With these informations you should have a good starting point to correct read in the GPS data. Visualization of these informations to the user (like showing a Map with the current position) is another task. But [maps.google.com API](http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html) would be a possible candidate if you software runs on a machine with internet connection and you don't mind the costs for this connection.

Comment: There are a number of such online APIs. As the OP is working with C#, the Bing Maps range of online APIs are probably a better choice (all other things being equal). They include web services, JavaScript AJAX, and Silverlight, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have started study those. But I have edited my question. So, please give me some better ones.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are asking this question strongly suggests you do not have the resources or ability to write it from scratch (it is a substantial project). Therefore you will have to use existing toolkits. You mention Silverlight, so I suspect you are going to be working in an online environment. Therefore I would recommend the Bing Maps Silverlight Control. IMHO, this outperforms the Google Maps control at the moment - but it is a moving target. This is a place where active competition results in two products (Google Maps & Bing Maps) constantly trying to out do each other.

If this is for a commercial application, then check the EULAs for these services - although many enthusiasts assume they are free, this is not necessarily the case. Most commercial applications cost significant sums ($1000s per month). In such a situation, the choice of service will probably come down to cost rather than technology.